# Laravel 5.8 redirect returns 200 but doesn’t open the page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

The issue is I redirect the user to specific external URL with laravel redirect in a condition, and the condition is true, but redirect only logs in the network and doesn’t really change URL in the browser. I also tried the header function in pure PHP but it didn’t help.

here is my code:

```
public function purchase(Request $request, Transaction $transaction, User $user_model)
{
    $username = $request->input('username');
    if (!isset($username)) {
        $this->setMessage(400, 'پر کردن فیلد username الزامی است');
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'data' => $this->getMessage()]);
    }
    $user = $user_model->scopeGetUserId($username);
    if ($user == null) {
        $this->setMessage(404, 'کاربر یافت نشد');
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'data' => $this->getMessage()], 200);
    }
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $diet_type_id = $request->input('diet_type_id');
    $price = 100;

        $Amount = $price; //Amount will be based on Toman  - Required
        $Description = "پرداخت مبلغ $price تومان برای دریافت رژیم از سلامتپاد";  // Required
        $Email = 'm.esmiran@gmail.com'; // Optional
        $Mobile = '09123456789'; // Optional
        $CallbackURL = 'http://salamatpaad.com/test/public/api/verify/' . $user_id . '/' . $diet_type_id;  // Required
        $client = new SoapClient('https://ir.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl', array('encoding' => 'UTF-8'));

        $result = $client->PaymentRequest(
            array(
                'MerchantID' => $transaction->scopeGetMerchantId(),
                'Amount' => $Amount,
                'Description' => $Description,
                'Email' => $Email,
                'Mobile' => $Mobile,
                'CallbackURL' => $CallbackURL
            )
        );
        //Redirect to URL You can do it also by creating a form
        if ($result->Status == 100) {
            return redirect()->to('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/' . $result->Authority);
        } else {
            echo 'ERR: ' . $result->Status;
        }

}
```

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxi84.png)

Comment: It seems to be broken... what answer you expect with this description of problem??

Comment: Show your code please. If you're using Ajax to get the redirected url, then you're going to have to use javascript/jquery to perform the redirect.

Comment: You mean that i can not redirect from the server-side? ‘Cause I’m using redirect laravel function

Comment: It just depends on how you're doing the redirect, and how you're triggering it. Without code, we couldn't tell you exactly what's going on.

Comment: What information do you need? @panther

Comment: Paste your code in your question.

Comment: guys I've added my code to the question. would you help me? i don't have enough time

Comment: How do you perform the request on browser ? just type the url on browser or are you using js/jquery to make the request ?

Comment: the request sent to this method by axios in vuejs. but as far as I know, it's laravel that must redirect to the url. I've done this before successfuly and I don't know why it's not working now

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-external-domains), for redirecting to external links, use the `redirect()->away()` method.

Comment: thank you but i've tried away(), to() and redirect('url'). none of them works